# Xamarin.Forms error install package

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Package installer I get this error, gave this error in other packages

> Error Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads
>   60.1142.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the
>   package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
>   are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install this package into your Android project, not your Portable Class Library. It is a Android-only library that cannot work cross-platform. As you can see on the project's GitHub page:

> Xamarin creates and maintains Xamarin.Android bindings for the Google Play Services Client Library

The library is not a C# library, but it rather contains bindings to native Java-based libraries and hence compatible only with Android.